# Passing a record from a Flow to an Apex class

Tags: apex, visual-workflow

So, if I search for `InvocableMethod` there is a lot of documentation such as this:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm

And if I search for "pass record from Flow to Apex code" I see some examples like this:

[https://www.crmscience.com/single-post/invoking-apex-with-flow-using-salesforce#:~:text=Invoke%20Apex%20From%20Flow.&text=After%20collecting%20the%20data%20or,parameters%20as%20variables%20you%20defined](https://www.crmscience.com/single-post/invoking-apex-with-flow-using-salesforce#:%7E:text=Invoke%20Apex%20From%20Flow.&text=After%20collecting%20the%20data%20or,parameters%20as%20variables%20you%20defined).

But I can't find a single example that shows sending the main record from Flow to Apex. But I think this would be common?

Assume I have a Flow that is triggered on create or update for an Opportunity. So the Opportunity should be `$Record`? Assume I have written an Apex class with an `InvocableMethod`. It is clear, from the documentation, how to call this Apex code from the Flow, but it is not clear how I would specify that I want to pass the Opportunity record to the `InvocableMethod`. Can someone explain what I need to specify in the Flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Invocable` method will only accept these parameters as input as per the [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm).

> There can be at most one input parameter and its data type must be one
> of the following:
>
> 1. A list of a primitive data type or a list of lists of a primitive
>    data type – the generic Object type isn’t supported.
> 2. A list of an sObject type or a list of lists of an sObject type.
> 3. A list of the generic sObject type (List) or a list of
>    lists of the generic sObject type (List<List>).
> 4. A list of a user-defined type, containing variables of the
>    supported types or user-defined Apex types, with the
>    InvocableVariable annotation. Create a custom global or public Apex
>    class to implement your data type, and make sure that your class
>    contains at least one member variable with the invocable variable
>    annotation.

In your scenario you can use `List<Opportunity>` as input parameter as below.

```
public class  senddatafromflowtoapex {
 @InvocableMethod (label = 'oppy flow' description = 'send oppy data to apex')
    
    public static void  senddata ( List<opportunity> opplist) {
        //logic here
    }
}
```

In the flow you can just give $Record as a parameter as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is great.